# Ubuntu phpmyadmin installtio gui problem- dont see my new installed program (phpmyadmin) in programs gui list on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Ubuntu phpmyadmin installtio gui problem-  dont see my new installed program (phpmyadmin) in programs gui list on ubuntu 10.04.
I install phpmy admin with Synaptic package manager.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web-based apps like that don't tend to turn up on the main desktop menus.

You should be able to access the newly installed scripts by browsing to `http://<hostname>/phpmyadmin` (which if you are working on the same machine you have installed it on will be http://localhost/phpmyadmin) using Firefox or what-ever other browser you have installed.

If that URL does not work, have a look in the config file that was added to the directory  /etc/apache2/conf.d when the package was installed to see what virtual directories it is creating. (if you are using lighttpd, or something else, rather then Apache, then this config detail will be in a slightly different place of course)

Comment: Hi, i can access in http://localhost/phpmyadmin but my username and password not give me permission to enter.
(I didnt set password to mysql)
Thank you,
Yosef

Comment: Yosef, you'll need to reset your root mysql password. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205614/how-to-change-mysql-root-password-to-default